# Combine two Pandas dataframes if unique values found in some columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Pandas dataframes in Python that looks something like this example:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns = ['file', 'comments', 'priority', 'id'])
df_test.file = ['file_1', 'file_1_v2', 'file_2_old', 'file_2_new', 'file_3', 'file_4_v1', 'file_4_v2']
df_test.comments = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'ghi', 'pqr', 'uvw', 'pqr']
df_test.priority = [10, 100, 15, 25, 50, 20, 40]
df_test.id = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]

df_test2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns = ['file', 'comments', 'priority', 'id'])
df_test2.file = ['file_1', 'file_1_test', 'file_2_old', 'file_3_s', 'file_4_v3', 'file_4_v4']
df_test2.comments = ['abd', 'def', 'xya', 'pqr', 'uvw', 'pqr']
df_test2.priority = [10, 110, 35, 50, 20, 50]
df_test2.id = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

What I want to do is to add the rows from the second dataframe into the first one, but only if it has unique values in either 'comments' or 'priority' that are not found in the first dataframe for all entries with the same 'id' value.

In the example, it would mean that we would add row 1, 2, 3, and 6 from the second dataframe, since these have unique values in those two columns for the given 'id' number.

I suppose I could concatenate the two and drop duplicates like this:

```
df_test3 = pd.concat([df_test, df_test2])
df_test3 = df_test3.drop_duplicates(subset = ['comments', 'priority'], keep = 'first')
```

But this also drops row 6 from dataframe two, as it is not unique compared to a row with another 'id' number. What I want is for it to check if the rows are unique only to their own 'id' number. Any help on how to do it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you indeed want to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with a `subset`. You should however include `'id'` in the subset:

```
out = (pd.concat([df_test, df_test2])
         .drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'comments', 'priority'])
       )
```

Output:

```
          file comments  priority  id
0       file_1      abc        10   1
1    file_1_v2      def       100   1
2   file_2_old      xyz        15   2
3   file_2_new      ghi        25   2
4       file_3      pqr        50   3
5    file_4_v1      uvw        20   4
6    file_4_v2      pqr        40   4
0       file_1      abd        10   1
1  file_1_test      def       110   1
2   file_2_old      xya        35   2
5    file_4_v4      pqr        50   4
```